Migrating from Bind9 to PowerDNS - forwarders
I have been studying how to migrate the Bind9 DNS server to PowerDNS, but I am stuck in the following situation:
In Bind9 in the named.conf file, I have the "forwarders" settings for 8.8.8.8, so I can have internet and internal dns.
options {
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };
    allow-query { internal; };
};

How to do this in PowerDNS? I'm not sure if PowerDNS-Recursor is for this and how to configure it.
As it is, using PowerDNS, the hosts perfectly resolve the internal DNSs, there are 4 zones. But they are completely without internet access.

From everything I'm seeing online, I'm not sure Powerdns is a good replacement for Bind in a typical home/lab network. It separates the ideas of query resolution from zone hosting. Not an expert here, but every post i see on the topic indicates that people trying to use PowerDNS as they might with Bind (forwarding queries with local NX responses) are thinking about it wrong. good luck.

Well, I still prefer Bind for its simplicity, but the fact that it doesn't have a decent backend database always leaves a reason for a change.
